# Firebase form saves url to database on second click.For the first click it saves empty url in database,React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am new to the firebase database and trying to upload a form that has an image file and video file and save the downloaded URL to real-time database at the same time. On submit form for the first time the image file and video file are saved to storage but the URLs are empty in the database. On a second click, the image and video files are uploaded and saved correctly. I don't understand what is happening on the first click. Here is a truncated part of my code that handles the upload and saving to firebase.

```
const thumnailUpload = async () => {
    try {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref_storage(
        storage,
        `products_test/${Date.now() + title}`
      );
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, thumbnail);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Thumbnail Upload is " + progress + "% done");
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Thumbnail Upload is paused");
              break;
            case "running":
              console.log("Thumbnail Upload is running");
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          toast.error(error.message);
        },
        async () => {
          let downloadUrlThumbnail1 = await getDownloadURL(
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref
          );
          setThumbnailUrl(downloadUrlThumbnail1);
          console.log("Thumbnail Upload is completed");
          console.log(thumbnailUrl);
          toast.success("Thumbnail Upload is completed");
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleVideoUpload = async () => {
    try {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref_storage(
        storage,
        `products_test/${Date.now() + title}`
      );

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, mainContent);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Video Upload is " + progress + "% done");
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log(" Video Upload is paused");
              break;
            case "running":
              console.log("Video Upload is running");
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          toast.error(error.message);
        },
        async () => {
          let downloadUrlVideo = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
          setContentUrl(downloadUrlVideo);
          console.log("Video Upload is completed");
          console.log(contentUrl);
          toast.success("Video Upload is completed");
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const addProduct = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleVideoUpload();
    thumnailUpload();

    const writeUserData = async (
      title,
      description,
      price,
      category,
      type,
      thumbnailUrl,
      contentUrl
    ) => {
      const db = getDatabase();
      await set(ref_database(db, "testproducts/"), {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        contentType: type,
        category: category,
        price: price,
        imgUrl: thumbnailUrl,
        videoUrl: contentUrl,
        uploader: currentUser.uid,
      });
    };

    writeUserData(
      title,
      description,
      price,
      category,
      type,
      thumbnailUrl,
      contentUrl
    );
  };
```

I have tried using async await but still not working as I had wanted.I am a beginner and I may be making an obvious mistake.Thanks

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem,I found a workaround for this by writing the uploadfiles function as a separate custom hook and then imported the hook to the form.